# PID output at 0 error

Tags: pid-controller

I'm having some problems conceptualizing PID, specifically the case where there is 0 error.

The traditional PID formula I usually find is:
\$ output=K_p e + K_i \int e dt + K_d \frac {de}{dt} \$

Let's assume I'm running a motor with the above equation. If the control loop was perfect and the error goes to 0 for a long time, then the controller output also goes to 0.  This would cause the motor output to go to 0 also.

I would think the PID algorithm would need to be either:

\$ outputnew = K_p e + K_i \int e dt + K_d \frac {de}{dt} + outputold\$

or

\$ outputnew = K_p e + K_i \int e dt + K_d \frac {de}{dt} + fixedoutput\$

I know I'm not explaining it very well.

Comment: Hi. You might also want to watch [this YouTube video by Aerospace Controls Laboratory  at MIT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Y7zG48uHRo). It may help a lot.

Comment: I've added MathJAX versions of your equations. If you're happy with them then you may delete the text versions.

Comment: See if my answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/346730/understanding-the-flow-of-a-pi-controller/346759?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C23.1040#346759 helps your understanding.

Comment: I think what you're assuming is that is that if the error goes to zero, the integral of the error would also go to zero. This is not true. If the error is zero, the integral of the error would remain constant.

Answer (score 20):

The controller output does not go to zero because the integral variable holds the exact value (modulo integral gain) required to maintain the output at the required level, ideally, and in steady state.

Answer (score 15):

For the proportional compensator (P), a zero error input will result in a 0 valued control sugnal.

For a derivative compensator (D), any constant error input will result in a 0 valued control signal.

For a integral compensator (I), a zero error input will result in a constant (different from zero) valued control signal. Any error not equal to zero will cause the integrator's value to change.

The integrator is the only device where putting nothing in will produce an output. If there is an error signal, the integrator will move to reduce the error to zero. It goes in the right direction due to negative feedback.

So when the actual value of the controlled variable is the same as its desired value, then the integrator will output exactly the right control signal and hold it there.

Answer (score 4):

As other answers have detailed, a normal PID holds its output value by means of the integrator.

However, the two formulas you mention are also suitable for specific use cases:

> outputnew=kperror+KierrorIntegral+KderrorDerivative + fixedoutput

This is close to [feedforward PID](https://blog.incatools.com/benefits-feedforward-pid-controllers), where the `fixedoutput` would be e.g. `A * target_value`. The output term would be fixed in the sense that it doesn't depend on measured values, only on the desired target value.

This works especially well for processes that are mostly linear, so that the PID controller only needs to handle a small residual error. It will also react faster to any changes in the target value.

> outputnew=kperror+KierrorIntegral+KderrorDerivative+outputold

This is similar to PID controller followed by additional integrator. Practically the extra integrator converts D term into P, P term into I, and I into I².

For most processes a **P, I, I²** controller would have poor stability, but it can work well if the process is derivative by its physical nature. For example, if you try to control the charging current of a battery by controlling the voltage fed to it, the behavior of the battery itself cancels out the extra integrator. Though in practical cases the series resistance of the battery makes even a regular PID work well enough.

Answer (score 2):

An integrator with zero input will hold its value for as long as it's input is zero.  Basically, it remembers the error input backward in time until the system was turned on.

If the error is non zero, then the integrator will just push harder and harder until it is.

So, in the absence of any changing disturbance, once the system settles out to its target value, the error will be zero and the integrator will hold the value needed to keep the error at zero.